# why does blktrace only write blocks of 8?

Tags: linux, io, block-device

I want to understand the I/O pattern a database is writing to disk to decide how many disks to use for best performance. To analyse the I/O pattern I want to use blktrace and I have to grok it first. This is what I try here.

I have a USB stick that I attach to my computer and it becomes /dev/sdd. Now I start

```
dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/null
```

and on a separate window I start

```
blktrace -d /dev/sdd -o - | blkparse -i -
```

and expect to see read (R) operations that get merged (M) and put into the queue (Q). That works, but to my understanding the block size is always 8:

```
8,48   6    15257     2.157995037  2470  M   R 816696 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6    15258     2.157996273  2470  Q   R 816704 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6    15259     2.157996520  2470  M   R 816704 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6    15260     2.157997794  2470  Q   R 816712 + 8 [dd]
```

Now I am stopping everything and tell the system to read only one byte:

```
dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/null count=1 bs=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte (1 B) copied, 0.00325544 s, 0.3 kB/s
```

This shows up on the blkparse console like this:

```
8,48   6        1    17.220316681  2543  G   N [dd]
8,48   6        2    17.220317209  2543  I   N 0 (00 ..) [dd]
8,48   6        3    17.220317707  2543  D   N 0 (00 ..) [dd]
8,48   6        4    17.220787473  2543  Q   R 0 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6        5    17.220790545  2543  G   R 0 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6        6    17.220791330  2543  P   N [dd]
8,48   6        7    17.220793515  2543  Q   R 8 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6        8    17.220794597  2543  M   R 8 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6        9    17.220796134  2543  Q   R 16 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6       10    17.220796419  2543  M   R 16 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6       11    17.220797695  2543  Q   R 24 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6       12    17.220797943  2543  M   R 24 + 8 [dd]
8,48   6       13    17.220798862  2543  I   R 0 + 32 [dd]
```

what's going on here? Why does a read of ***one byte*** show up as 3 "R" requests, each with a Q and a M action? Why does it "seem to" read 32 or 24 bytes? Where is docutainment to educate me further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are doing buffered IO and the page cache works in whole pages, which are 4k on PCs, or 8 512 byte sectors.  The kernel readahead mechanism also reads a bit more on the assumption that dd will continue reading.  If you want to avoid this, then you need to use direct IO by passing dd the iflag=direct option, but you won't be able to have it read a single byte doing that -- direct IO must be aligned to, and an even multiple of the sector size.

Answer (score 2):

In blktrace, the figure after + is the request size in sector size (which is usually 512 bytes, you can use blockdev --report to check)

So in your trace, total read is actually 16kbytes.

So why there are 4 'R' requests, the reason i can think of is read ahead. i did a test by setting read ahead to be 512 bytes only by using the following command:

```
blockdev --setra 1 /dev/sdd
```

Looking at the read_ahead_kb shows 0

```
more /sys/block/sdd/queue/read_ahead_kb
0
```

And the trace i get from executing your dd command is as follow:

```
8,48   0        1     0.000000000 14412  Q   R 0 + 8 [dd]
8,48   0        2     0.000002577 14412  G   R 0 + 8 [dd]
8,48   0        3     0.000004467 14412  P   N [dd]
8,48   0        4     0.000005627 14412  I   R 0 + 8 [dd]
8,48   0        5     0.000007362 14412  U   N [dd] 1
8,48   0        6     0.000008238 14412  D   R 0 + 8 [dd]
8,48   0        7     0.018772074     0  C   R 0 + 8 [0]
CPU0 (dd_bs1_c1):
Reads Queued:           1,        4KiB  Writes Queued:           0,        0KiB
Read Dispatches:        1,        4KiB  Write Dispatches:        0,        0KiB
Reads Requeued:         0               Writes Requeued:         0
Reads Completed:        1,        4KiB  Writes Completed:        0,        0KiB
Read Merges:            0,        0KiB  Write Merges:            0,        0KiB
Read depth:             1               Write depth:             0
IO unplugs:             1               Timer unplugs:           0
```

So as of why it reads 4kbytes instead of 1 byte, i believe this is because of the FS block size which is 4kBytes. So it is the minimum that will get read.